# Ejecutar un programa con mpi

Tags: c, linux

paso a contarles mi problema. Estoy intentando ejecutar un programa utilizando la libreria mpi en linux mint. Descargue el paquete y tengo descargada la libreria. Puedo compilar mi programa (mpicc) pero cuando intento ejecutarlo utilizando mpirun me aparece el siguiente mensaje: 
`

`[proxy:0:0@miMachine-LinuxMint] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:75): execvp error on file hola (No such file or directory)
[proxy:0:0@miMachine-LinuxMint] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:75): execvp error on file hola (No such file or directory)
[proxy:0:0@miMachine-LinuxMint] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:75): [proxy:0:0@miMachine-LinuxMint] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:75): execvp error on file hola (No such file or directory)
execvp error on file hola (No such file or directory)
[proxy:0:0@miMachine-LinuxMint] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:75): execvp error on file hola (No such file or directory)`

Mi archivo se llama hola.Lamentablemente no puedo poner una etiqueta de mpi en el foro. 
Si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia sera bienvenida.
Saludos.

Comment: creo qu esta todo bien, estas seguro que estas en el directorio de tu archivo? utiliza `pwd` para averguarlo, si es asi localiza el directorio y ejecutalo alli con el comando `cd`

Comment: Hola. Si estoy en el directorio de mi archivo.

Comment: entonces esta mal instalado

Comment: Intentare instalarlo de nuevo. Gracias por tu aporte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno logre hacerlo funcionar. Parece ser que para compilar archivos mpi es necesario instalar un paquete y para ejecutarlos otro paquete. No soy experto en linux ni en manejo de paquetes y no repare en ello. 
Primero instale el paquete para compilar.

> apt-get install lam4-dev

Luego el paquete para ejecutar

> apt-get install lam-runtime

Finalmente active el paquete de ejecucion.

> lamboot

Aqui esta la salida para la ejecucion del programa en 5 procesos.

> ```
> Hola! Soy el 0 de 5
> Hola! Soy el 2 de 5
> Hola! Soy el 1 de 5
> Hola! Soy el 3 de 5
> Hola! Soy el 4 de 5
> ```

Gracias por tu respuesta @Renato A.